# Resolving ambiguous overload of operator[]

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I have this class:

```
class MyClass {

    public:

        int operator[](const std::string&);
        const std::string& operator[](const int&) const;

    ...
};
```

It works greatly, however, if i call the second operator w/ const literal 0:

```
MyClass myclass;
std::cout << myclass[0] << std::endl;
```

I got this error:

```
In function 'int main()':
ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' in 'myclass[0]'
note: candidates are:
note: const int MyClass::operator[](const string&)|
note: const string& MyClass::operator[](const int&) const
```

I guess i understand what's the situation (0 can be either a string or int?), but my question is: is there any way to resolve this and keep the operator overloading?

Comment: Why bother with `const int&`? Just take an `int`.

Comment: The `string` version matches because a const literal zero can be implicitly cast to a null `const char*` pointer and from there to `std::string`.  Still thinking about how to avoid this.

Comment: Pubby: It won't help here.

Comment: I'm surprised that these are considered equal rank conversions.

Comment: I have a feeling that `0` can also be a pointer and that's making the string constructor viable. Workaround: `int n = 0; myclass[n];`. Better: `static_cast<MyClass const &>(myclass)[0]`.

Comment: Returning `const int` is weird (and meaningless).

Comment: @sftrabbit: It's beacause of the `const` qualification on the instance. Without it one would be a better overload.

Comment: Carl: Yeah, in the first version i returned `const int&`, forgot to change it.

Comment: what compiler are you using? and did you miss to const qualify the first functions? do you post actual example?

Comment: Latest stable MINGW GCC, i don't think is considered as broken. And from the answer, it seems the error message is totally legal. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `MyClass::operator[](const std::string&)` involves converting:

`myclass` from `MyClass&` to `MyClass&`: perfect match

`0` from `int` to `const char*` to `std::string`: user-defined conversion

Calling `MyClass::operator[](const int&) const` involves converting:

`myclass` from `MyClass&` to `const MyClass&`: const qualification

`0` from `int` to `int`: perfect match

In a situation like this, when one overload is "better" for argument X but a different overload is "better" for argument Y, neither overload can be considered the best overload, and the compiler must complain (assuming no third overload beats both).

Is it possible to change the two overloads to be both `const` or both `non-const`?  If not, you could add a third overload to handle this sort of situation:

```
const std::string& operator[](int n) {
    return static_cast<const MyClass&>(*this)[n];
}
```

Comment: const qualification conversion is a standard conversion, while string(0) is a user-defined conversion, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks! As i mentioned in my comment to Kerrek's answer, i changed the second overload to be non-const, and it worked.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: Only ICS-es for the same argument are compared.  The ambiguous overload error is correct.

Answer (score 4):

`0` cannot be a `string`, but it can be a pointer which means it can be *implicitly converted* to a `string`.  Note that this isn't true of other constant integrals, like `1` or `42` -- just `0` specifically.

**4.10 Pointer Conversion**

> 1/A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19)
>   rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. A null pointer constant
>   can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer
>   value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of
>   pointer to object or pointer to function type. Two null pointer values
>   of the same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer
>   constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion, and
>   not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification
>   conversion (4.4).

So, in the case of `myclass[0]`, `0` can be either an `int`, or ` null pointer constant.

The Standard also dictates that `std::string` has a non-`explicit` constructor which takes a `char` pointer:

```
size_type find_last_not_of (const charT* s, size_type pos = npos) const;
```

Now, since your `operator&` methods both take parameters of `const` reference type, they can be passed temporaries.  This is why the compiler is confused -- it doesn't know which one you want -- the one that takes an `int`, or the one that takes a temporary `string` constructed via `string(const char*)`.

As for how to solve this problem, I'd take a step back.  It seems to me that your two `operator[]` functions do distinctly different things.  Or perhaps they do the same thing, given different inputs.  If they do different things, then I would provide member functions that have different (appropriate) names, and skip trying to use the `operator[]` syntax.  Perhaps one of those methods returns something that really is indexed -- in that case, I'd use the `operator[]` syntax for that one, but only that one.

If they do actually do the same thing, and that thing is to return an item *by index*, then I would provide only one method for this, and have it take a `size_t` by value.  You can then also provide some kind of conversion function (preferably in the form of a free, non-member function) that converts from, say, a `string` to a `size_t`.  Doing this, you can write your code like this when indexing by `string`:

```
myPos[str_to_index(str)];
```

Answer (score 3):

The literal `0` is special. Apart from being an octal constant, it can also be converted into a null pointer of any pointer type. That makes `0` viable for the `char const *`-constructor of `std::string`.

The reason that neither overload is better is because the int overload of the operator has the `const` instance CV qualifier. That way, both overloads require a conversion and are equally bad.

The obvious workaround is to be explicit about wanting the const overload:

```
static_cast<MyClass const &>(myclass)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! For now, i just removed the `const` CV qualifier as a workaround.

Comment: For those who are confused, there are two arguments: the this pointer and the argument that goes inside the parentheses. The first version of the operator requires no conversion for the first argument, and an int-to-pointer conversion followed by a user-defined conversion for the second argument. The second version of the operator requires a const-conversion on the first argument, and no conversion on the second. So the first version is better on the first argument, and the second version is better on the second argument. Since neither is the same or better for all arguments, it's ambiguous